# Node unbound for immediate claim volume in EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

I create one EKS cluster with 6 nodes. In every node attach EFS file system using launch template and create a file in file system and file also accessible from all worker node. By SSH i check this operation.

But when try to create a test-application pod with dynamic pvc claim after installing csi driver and storage class creation in eks, cluster tell me,

**PVC Pod:**

```
Normal  ExternalProvisioning    2 hours persistentvolume-controller waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "efs.csi.aws.com" or manually created by system administrator
```

**Application Pod:**

```
FailedScheduling    2 hours default-scheduler   0/6 nodes are available: 6 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
```

How can i fix this efs issues from eks....? please give me some guidance. I am stucking in here almost 1 months.

**PVC describe:**

```
{
  "kind": "PersistentVolumeClaim",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "efs-claim",
    "namespace": "default",
    "uid": "bb7d1d08-f14b-4435-90e2-42255a915e23",
    "resourceVersion": "9805",
    "creationTimestamp": "2022-07-18T03:50:14Z",
    "annotations": {
      "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"kind\":\"PersistentVolumeClaim\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"efs-claim\",\"namespace\":\"default\"},\"spec\":{\"accessModes\":[\"ReadWriteMany\"],\"resources\":{\"requests\":{\"storage\":\"5Gi\"}},\"storageClassName\":\"eks-sc-efs\"}}\n",
      "volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner": "efs.csi.aws.com"
    },
    "finalizers": [
      "kubernetes.io/pvc-protection"
    ],
    "managedFields": [
      {
        "manager": "kube-controller-manager",
        "operation": "Update",
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "time": "2022-07-18T03:50:14Z",
        "fieldsType": "FieldsV1",
        "fieldsV1": {
          "f:metadata": {
            "f:annotations": {
              "f:volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner": {}
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "manager": "kubectl-client-side-apply",
        "operation": "Update",
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "time": "2022-07-18T03:50:14Z",
        "fieldsType": "FieldsV1",
        "fieldsV1": {
          "f:metadata": {
            "f:annotations": {
              ".": {},
              "f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": {}
            }
          },
          "f:spec": {
            "f:accessModes": {},
            "f:resources": {
              "f:requests": {
                ".": {},
                "f:storage": {}
              }
            },
            "f:storageClassName": {},
            "f:volumeMode": {}
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "spec": {
    "accessModes": [
      "ReadWriteMany"
    ],
    "resources": {
      "requests": {
        "storage": "5Gi"
      }
    },
    "storageClassName": "eks-sc-efs",
    "volumeMode": "Filesystem"
  },
  "status": {
    "phase": "Pending"
  }
}
```

**Pod Describe:**

```
{
  "kind": "Pod",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "efs-app",
    "namespace": "default",
    "uid": "de410588-0fe4-4ea8-bb48-fe1fdbda30a0",
    "resourceVersion": "9809",
    "creationTimestamp": "2022-07-18T03:50:14Z",
    "annotations": {
      "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"kind\":\"Pod\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"efs-app\",\"namespace\":\"default\"},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"args\":[\"-c\",\"while true; do echo $(date -u) \\u003e\\u003e /data/out; sleep 5; done\"],\"command\":[\"/bin/sh\"],\"image\":\"centos\",\"name\":\"app\",\"volumeMounts\":[{\"mountPath\":\"/efs\",\"name\":\"persistent-storage\"}]}],\"volumes\":[{\"name\":\"persistent-storage\",\"persistentVolumeClaim\":{\"claimName\":\"efs-claim\"}}]}}\n",
      "kubernetes.io/psp": "eks.privileged"
    },
    "managedFields": [
      {
        "manager": "kube-scheduler",
        "operation": "Update",
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "time": "2022-07-18T03:50:14Z",
        "fieldsType": "FieldsV1",
        "fieldsV1": {
          "f:status": {
            "f:conditions": {
              ".": {},
              "k:{\"type\":\"PodScheduled\"}": {
                ".": {},
                "f:lastProbeTime": {},
                "f:lastTransitionTime": {},
                "f:message": {},
                "f:reason": {},
                "f:status": {},
                "f:type": {}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "manager": "kubectl-client-side-apply",
        "operation": "Update",
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "time": "2022-07-18T03:50:14Z",
        "fieldsType": "FieldsV1",
        "fieldsV1": {
          "f:metadata": {
            "f:annotations": {
              ".": {},
              "f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": {}
            }
          },
          "f:spec": {
            "f:containers": {
              "k:{\"name\":\"app\"}": {
                ".": {},
                "f:args": {},
                "f:command": {},
                "f:image": {},
                "f:imagePullPolicy": {},
                "f:name": {},
                "f:resources": {},
                "f:terminationMessagePath": {},
                "f:terminationMessagePolicy": {},
                "f:volumeMounts": {
                  ".": {},
                  "k:{\"mountPath\":\"/efs\"}": {
                    ".": {},
                    "f:mountPath": {},
                    "f:name": {}
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "f:dnsPolicy": {},
            "f:enableServiceLinks": {},
            "f:restartPolicy": {},
            "f:schedulerName": {},
            "f:securityContext": {},
            "f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds": {},
            "f:volumes": {
              ".": {},
              "k:{\"name\":\"persistent-storage\"}": {
                ".": {},
                "f:name": {},
                "f:persistentVolumeClaim": {
                  ".": {},
                  "f:claimName": {}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "spec": {
    "volumes": [
      {
        "name": "persistent-storage",
        "persistentVolumeClaim": {
          "claimName": "efs-claim"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "kube-api-access-ppzjw",
        "projected": {
          "sources": [
            {
              "serviceAccountToken": {
                "expirationSeconds": 3607,
                "path": "token"
              }
            },
            {
              "configMap": {
                "name": "kube-root-ca.crt",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "key": "ca.crt",
                    "path": "ca.crt"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "downwardAPI": {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "path": "namespace",
                    "fieldRef": {
                      "apiVersion": "v1",
                      "fieldPath": "metadata.namespace"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "defaultMode": 420
        }
      }
    ],
    "containers": [
      {
        "name": "app",
        "image": "centos",
        "command": [
          "/bin/sh"
        ],
        "args": [
          "-c",
          "while true; do echo $(date -u) >> /data/out; sleep 5; done"
        ],
        "resources": {},
        "volumeMounts": [
          {
            "name": "persistent-storage",
            "mountPath": "/efs"
          },
          {
            "name": "kube-api-access-ppzjw",
            "readOnly": true,
            "mountPath": "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount"
          }
        ],
        "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
        "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
        "imagePullPolicy": "Always"
      }
    ],
    "restartPolicy": "Always",
    "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
    "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
    "serviceAccountName": "default",
    "serviceAccount": "default",
    "securityContext": {},
    "schedulerName": "default-scheduler",
    "tolerations": [
      {
        "key": "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready",
        "operator": "Exists",
        "effect": "NoExecute",
        "tolerationSeconds": 300
      },
      {
        "key": "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable",
        "operator": "Exists",
        "effect": "NoExecute",
        "tolerationSeconds": 300
      }
    ],
    "priority": 0,
    "enableServiceLinks": true,
    "preemptionPolicy": "PreemptLowerPriority"
  },
  "status": {
    "phase": "Pending",
    "conditions": [
      {
        "type": "PodScheduled",
        "status": "False",
        "lastProbeTime": null,
        "lastTransitionTime": "2022-07-18T03:50:14Z",
        "reason": "Unschedulable",
        "message": "0/6 nodes are available: 6 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims."
      }
    ],
    "qosClass": "BestEffort"
  }
}
```

**Storage Class Descibe:**

```
{
  "kind": "StorageClass",
  "apiVersion": "storage.k8s.io/v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "eks-sc-efs",
    "uid": "9ea3d917-ef15-4863-ae62-e0de929c3134",
    "resourceVersion": "2756",
    "creationTimestamp": "2022-07-18T03:35:09Z",
    "annotations": {
      "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"allowVolumeExpansion\":true,\"apiVersion\":\"storage.k8s.io/v1\",\"kind\":\"StorageClass\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"eks-sc-efs\"},\"mountOptions\":[\"tls\"],\"parameters\":{\"basePath\":\"/\",\"directoryPerms\":\"700\",\"fileSystemId\":\"fs-0c8427977faa4865c\",\"gidRangeEnd\":\"2000\",\"gidRangeStart\":\"1000\",\"provisioningMode\":\"efs-ap\"},\"provisioner\":\"efs.csi.aws.com\"}\n"
    },
    "managedFields": [
      {
        "manager": "kubectl-client-side-apply",
        "operation": "Update",
        "apiVersion": "storage.k8s.io/v1",
        "time": "2022-07-18T03:35:09Z",
        "fieldsType": "FieldsV1",
        "fieldsV1": {
          "f:allowVolumeExpansion": {},
          "f:metadata": {
            "f:annotations": {
              ".": {},
              "f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": {}
            }
          },
          "f:mountOptions": {},
          "f:parameters": {
            ".": {},
            "f:basePath": {},
            "f:directoryPerms": {},
            "f:fileSystemId": {},
            "f:gidRangeEnd": {},
            "f:gidRangeStart": {},
            "f:provisioningMode": {}
          },
          "f:provisioner": {},
          "f:reclaimPolicy": {},
          "f:volumeBindingMode": {}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "provisioner": "efs.csi.aws.com",
  "parameters": {
    "basePath": "/",
    "directoryPerms": "700",
    "fileSystemId": "fs-*******4865c",
    "gidRangeEnd": "2000",
    "gidRangeStart": "1000",
    "provisioningMode": "efs-ap"
  },
  "reclaimPolicy": "Delete",
  "mountOptions": [
    "tls"
  ],
  "allowVolumeExpansion": true,
  "volumeBindingMode": "Immediate"
}
```

Comment: Have you created the actual PVC object prior to creating a Pod?

Comment: yes create pvc before pod

Comment: Could you please paste your pod, pvc and sc manifests? Can you also kubectl describe your PVC ?

Comment: i added pod, pvc and sc maifest

Answer (score 1):

According to the PVC status pending,  there is no provisioner able to create the Volume. Have you try and create a PersistentVolume?

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: test-volume
spec:
  storageClassName: eks-sc-efs
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
```

Describe the object and see if there are any other errors. Additionally make sure the CSI drivers are installed. I found this documentation from AWS EKS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html

Comment: its giving error "The PersistentVolume "test-volume" is invalid: spec: Required value: must specify a volume type"

Comment: my bad, you cannot create a PV like that with a storageClassName. Did you check the link for the EFS documentation? 

* is your IAM and Policy role in place? 
* is the EFS CSI Driver installed in your cluster? if so, check the logs maybe in the logs you find what is the issue you are having. 
* Do you have an EFS Filesystem installed on AWS?

What gives this command? `kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep efs-csi-controller`

Comment: yes all are installed properly.... and thanks to you